# gsutil: Unable to find the server at www.googleapis.com

Tags: docker, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, gsutil, docker-for-mac

On **Docker for Mac 1.12.3** given this Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:jessie
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install --no-install-recommends --fix-missing -y -q \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    python \
    python-openssl \
    && \
  apt-get clean autoclean && \
  apt-get autoremove -y && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/{apt,dpkg,cache,log}/

ENV GOOGLE_CLOUD_SDK=/google-cloud-sdk
ENV PATH=$PATH:$GOOGLE_CLOUD_SDK/bin
RUN \
  export GOOGLE_SDK_URL=https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-sdk-134.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz && \
  mkdir $GOOGLE_CLOUD_SDK && \
  curl --silent $GOOGLE_SDK_URL | tar xvzf - -C $GOOGLE_CLOUD_SDK --strip-components=1 && \
  gcloud init
```

Running

```
docker build -t gsutil .
```

will yield

```
Welcome! This command will take you through the configuration of gcloud.

Your current configuration has been set to: [default]

You can skip diagnostics next time by using the following flag:
  gcloud init --skip-diagnostics

Network diagnostic detects and fixes local network connection issues.
Checking network connection..................done.
ERROR: Reachability Check failed.
    Cannot reach https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects (ServerNotFoundError)
    Cannot reach https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform (ServerNotFoundError)
    Cannot reach https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/components-2.json (ServerNotFoundError)
Network connection problems may be due to proxy or firewall settings.


Do you have a network proxy you would like to set in gcloud (Y/n)?
Select the proxy type:
 [1] HTTP
 [2] HTTP_NO_TUNNEL
 [3] SOCKS4
 [4] SOCKS5
Please enter your numeric choice:
ERROR: Network diagnostic (0/1 checks) failed.

Network errors detected.

Would you like to continue anyways (y/N)?
You can re-run diagnostics with the following command:
  gcloud info --run-diagnostics
```

Some fixes have been proposed here https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?can=2&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Stars%20Summary%20log&groupby=&sort=&id=1146 like:

```
gcloud config set custom_ca_certs_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Which fixes the `gcloud init` failures but when I try to operate on any of my buckets with `gsutil` I get:

```
DEBUG 1115 20:39:17.746218 http_wrapper.py] Caught server not found error, retrying: Unable to find the server at www.googleapis.com
```

My authentication method is `activate-service-account` with a JSON key as follow:

```
COPY ./mykey.json ./mykey.json
RUN gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=mykey.json
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

-- Update --

I backed an image from the dockerfile and pushed it to Docker Hub. To reproduce the problem download a GS key and rename it `key.json` and run:

```
docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd)/key.json:/key.json kilianciuffolo/gsutil bash
root@905045dd14eb:/# gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=/key.json && gsutil -D ls gs://my-test-bucket
```

Comment: After this setup, does curl work to www.googleapis.com?  I assume it does since curl retrieved the gcloud bundle from dl.google.com.  It may be useful to compare the HTTP request output of gsutil -D <your command> with curl to see what is different.  If curl doesn't work, then that is a good starting point for examining the network.

Comment: @TravisHobrla I have a hunch that this is a problem with the python HTTP client and certificates it's using. Setting `custom_ca_certs_file` fixes the gcloud CLI but not gsutil. `curl`ing https://www.googleapis.com/storage/etc.../ results in a Login error as expected.

Comment: That makes sense.  gsutil doesn't use gcloud's certs file config.  Can you try setting ca certs file for gsutil by adding to ~/.boto `[Boto]
ca_certificates_file = /path/to/file` (need a newline after [Boto] but StackOverflow doesn't allow newlines in comments)

Comment: @TravisHobrla tried that with no luck.

Comment: Are there any other differences between the HTTP request output for gsutil -D <your command> and curl to the same endpoint?  If not, could you send mail to gs-team@google.com with the gsutil -D log so I can follow up with you?

Comment: @TravisHobrla how about I just push the image to docker hub and you can run it and debug it? I can send instructions at gs-team@google.com

Comment: @TravisHobrla I updated my original post with the two lines to reproduce I hope it helps

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this through either the `docker run` or `docker build` commands in your post. gsutil works without issue for me in the shell spawned by the `docker run` command.  The `docker build` command actually doesn't finish for me using your Dockerfile, although it _did_ get past the reachability check before it failed.  Although probably unrelated to your network issue: I tweaked the end of your Dockerfile to get the build to succeed:  
`COPY ./key.json /key.json`, `RUN gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=/key.json`, `RUN gcloud init --console-only`

Comment: @mhouglum using my image you are able to ls on one of your buckets?

Comment: Yes. I also passed the gcloud reachability check without setting any special ca cert file.  I've tried both ways on two different machines, but I've still been unable to reproduce this myself.

Comment: @mhouglum that's strange are you running on what OS and Docker version? If the same container works on your machine it must be docker or a DNS problem.

Comment: @mhouglum Indeed I just ran a container from my image on coreos and it worked. Is it docker for mac then ?

Comment: That might very well be the case. I haven't been able to try reproducing this from a Mac host yet.

Comment: I just installed Docker on a MacBook on a different network than before, and I was still was not able to reproduce the reachability issue.  All my attempts have been with a freshly-installed version of Docker; two on Ubuntu, one on OSX 10.11.

Comment: @mhouglum I found a fix! in my compose file I use: `dns: 8.8.8.8` and it works now! The weird thing is that I have set up google DNS on my macbook as well. It looks like a bug with Docker for mac networking maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a fix!

In my compose file I use: `dns: 8.8.8.8` and it works perfectly now.

What's strange is that on my host machine macOS 10.12.1 with Docker for Mac 0.12.3 I am using Google DNS already.

Probably a bug in Docker networking / DNS?

Comment: Glad to hear it! I've updated https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=1146 as well with your workaround in case others encounter these DNS woes in the future.

Comment: I am not even using docker. Still getting this error on my mac machine. I add `8.8.8.8` DNS to system settings. The issue resolved.